Find maximum of $\left( \frac{9b+4c}{a}-6\right)\left( \frac{9c+4a}{b}-6\right)\left( \frac{9a+4b}{c}-6\right)$

Find maximum value of $P=\left( \frac{9b+4c}{a}-6\right)\left( \frac{9c+4a}{b}-6\right)\left( \frac{9a+4b}{c}-6\right)$ where $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers.

This can be simplified as $P=\left( \frac{9b+4c-6a}{a}\right)\left( \frac{9c+4a-6b}{b}\right)\left( \frac{9a+4b-6c}{c}\right)$
Now let,
$x=9b+4c-6a$
$y=9c+4a-6b$
$x=9a+4b-6c$
From these we get,
$4x+6y=70c\implies2x+3y=35c$------------1
$4y+6z=70a\implies2y+3z=35a$------------2
$4z+6x=70b\implies2z+3x=35b$------------3
$\therefore \dfrac{5^3\cdot7^3\cdot xyz}{(2x+3y)(2y+3z)(2z+3x)}$
How do I continue from here? My teacher says that it leads ultimately to an AM-GM Inequality, but I can't derive it.

Hint:
$$2x+3y=x+x+y+y+y $$
$$\therefore 2x+3y \ge 5 \sqrt[5]{x^2y^3}$$
$$2x+3y \ge 5x^{\frac{2}{5}}y^{\frac{3}{5}}$$

@LiKwokKeung Oh...so that would transform into the AM-GM Inequality, thanks a ton!!
